# How to change Angular Material Datepicker numbers to Arabic/Persian characters?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using a Jalali calendar with Angular material datepicker but I want to change English numbers to Arabic/Persian characters.

[image]

```
"۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹", "۰"
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"
```

How to change numbers & font of Angular Material Datepicker?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried implementing it and it worked perfectly for me.
just add the following provider to your module providers array:

```js
{ provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'fa-IR' }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the Stackblitz demo for this? It'll be really helpful,Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add custom date provider in material module that should be import in another modules:

material.module.ts:

```
import {MAT_DATE_FORMATS} from '@angular/material';
@NgModule({

    ...

    providers: [
    {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'fa-IR'},
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: CustomDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: PERSIAN_DATE_FORMATS}
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {
}


export const PERSIAN_DATE_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'jYYYY/jMM/jDD'
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'jYYYY/jMM/jDD',
    monthYearLabel: 'jYYYY jMMMM',
    dateA11yLabel: 'jYYYY/jMM/jDD',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'jYYYY jMMMM'
  }
};


import {DateAdapter} from "@angular/material";
import * as jalaliMoment from 'jalali-moment'; /*  npm i jalali-moment */

export class CustomDateAdapter extends DateAdapter<jalaliMoment.Moment> {

  constructor() {
    super();
    super.setLocale('fa');
  }

  getYear(date: jalaliMoment.Moment): number {
    return this.clone(date).jYear();
  }

  getMonth(date: jalaliMoment.Moment): number {
    return this.clone(date).jMonth();
  }

  getDate(date: jalaliMoment.Moment): number {
    return this.clone(date).jDate();
  }

  getDayOfWeek(date: jalaliMoment.Moment): number {
    return this.clone(date).day();
  }

  getMonthNames(style: 'long' | 'short' | 'narrow'): string[] {
    switch (style) {
      case 'long':
      case 'short':
        return jalaliMoment.localeData('fa').jMonths().slice(0);
      case 'narrow':
        return jalaliMoment.localeData('fa').jMonthsShort().slice(0);
    }
  }

  getDateNames(): string[] {
    const valuesArray = Array(31);
    for (let i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
      valuesArray[i] = String(i + 1);
    }
    return valuesArray;
  }

  getDayOfWeekNames(style: 'long' | 'short' | 'narrow'): string[] {
    switch (style) {
      case 'long':
        return jalaliMoment.localeData('fa').weekdays().slice(0);
      case 'short':
        return jalaliMoment.localeData('fa').weekdaysShort().slice(0);
      case 'narrow':
        return ['ی', 'د', 'س', 'چ', 'پ', 'ج', 'ش'];
    }
  }

  getYearName(date: jalaliMoment.Moment): string {
    return this.clone(date).jYear().toString();
  }

  getFirstDayOfWeek(): number {
    return jalaliMoment.localeData('fa').firstDayOfWeek();
  }

  getNumDaysInMonth(date: jalaliMoment.Moment): number {
    return this.clone(date).jDaysInMonth();
  }

  clone(date: jalaliMoment.Moment): jalaliMoment.Moment {
    return date.clone().locale('fa');
  }

  createDate(year: number, month: number, date: number): jalaliMoment.Moment {
    if (month < 0 || month > 11) {
      throw Error(
        `Invalid month index "${month}". Month index has to be between 0 and 11.`
      );
    }
    if (date < 1) {
      throw Error(`Invalid date "${date}". Date has to be greater than 0.`);
    }
    const result = jalaliMoment()
      .jYear(year).jMonth(month).jDate(date)
      .hours(0).minutes(0).seconds(0).milliseconds(0)
      .locale('fa');

    if (this.getMonth(result) !== month) {
      throw Error(`Invalid date ${date} for month with index ${month}.`);
    }
    if (!result.isValid()) {
      throw Error(`Invalid date "${date}" for month with index "${month}".`);
    }
    return result;
  }

  today(): jalaliMoment.Moment {
    return jalaliMoment().locale('fa');
  }

  parse(value: any, parseFormat: string | string[]): jalaliMoment.Moment | null {
    if (value && typeof value === 'string') {
      return jalaliMoment(value, parseFormat, 'fa');
    }
    return value ? jalaliMoment(value).locale('fa') : null;
  }

  format(date: jalaliMoment.Moment, displayFormat: string): string {
    date = this.clone(date);
    if (!this.isValid(date)) {
      throw Error('JalaliMomentDateAdapter: Cannot format invalid date.');
    }
    return date.format(displayFormat);
  }

  addCalendarYears(date: jalaliMoment.Moment, years: number): jalaliMoment.Moment {
    return this.clone(date).add(years, 'jYear');
  }

  addCalendarMonths(date: jalaliMoment.Moment, months: number): jalaliMoment.Moment {
    return this.clone(date).add(months, 'jmonth');
  }

  addCalendarDays(date: jalaliMoment.Moment, days: number): jalaliMoment.Moment {
    return this.clone(date).add(days, 'jDay');
  }

  toIso8601(date: jalaliMoment.Moment): string {
    return this.clone(date).format();
  }

  isDateInstance(obj: any): boolean {
    return jalaliMoment.isMoment(obj);
  }

  isValid(date: jalaliMoment.Moment): boolean {
    return this.clone(date).isValid();
  }

  invalid(): jalaliMoment.Moment {
    return jalaliMoment.invalid();
  }

  deserialize(value: any): jalaliMoment.Moment | null {
    let date;
    if (value instanceof Date) {
      date = jalaliMoment(value);
    }
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      if (!value) {
        return null;
      }
      date = jalaliMoment(value).locale('fa');
    }
    if (date && this.isValid(date)) {
      return date;
    }
    return super.deserialize(value);
  }
}
```

after add this code, you see calendar in persian local.

**UPDATE:**

for change your font globally in application you can set font in your theme.

my-theme.scss:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
$custom-typography: mat-typography-config(
  $font-family: 'IRANSans'
);
```

and for registering your theme:

angular.json:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "prj-name":{
       "architect": {
         "build": {
            "options": {
               "styles": [
                "src/styles.css",
                "src/assets/theme/my-theme.scss"
               ],            
            }
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have written this with DayJS instead of Moment.js. This implementation is right but it does not affect numbers

Comment: i suggest for using persian font for that like `IRANSans`. for example : `.mat-calendar {
    font-family: IRANSans;
}`

Answer (score 0):

if your site is in Persian language just user a font like "BYekan" this font just supports number in Farsi and there is no need to change the numbers in standard Farsi Unicode